# startActivity(intent) and resume to main activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I've got an app that creates an intent for the last.fm android app in which it will start the "recommended" station for my account when i press a button. The trick i'm trying to figure out is how do i get the phone back to my app without the user having to navigate back manually? Once it start the last.fm intent it takes you to the playlist and i need it to resume back to my app automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use startActivity(intent), you cannot. Alternatively, you can use startActivityForResult(Intent, int) and then stop the child activity with finishActivity(int requestCode).

Answer (score 1):

Call [Activity.finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()) whenever you want close the present Activity and get back to an earlier one.